# Convert date_histogram interval in seconds in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I have a set of documents in ES that represent an accumulated value with respect to time. For example:

```
{
    "timestamp": ...,
    "raindrops_seen": 40,
    ...
}
```

I'd like to create a query where I can get the average rate (ie of raindrops) for a specified interval in a date_histogram aggregation. I can sum up the results for the field but I don't know how to get the interval in seconds. I was hoping there was a simple way to do this within the query without having to convert to seconds beforehand.

```
{
    "query": {
        ...
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "by_hour": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "timestamp",
                "interval": "0.5h",
                "extended_bounds": {
                    "min": "now/d-5h",
                    "max": "now/d-1h"
                }
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "sum_raindrops": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "raindrops_seen"
                    }
                },
                "avg_scripts": {
                    "bucket_script": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "var_sum_raindrops": "sum_raindrops"
                        },
                        "script": "var_sum_raindrops / (?)"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a straightforward way to convert "0.5h" or whatever is specified in the interval to seconds? The date histogram supports intervals as specified in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/common-options.html#time-units, and also strings like "week" and "day". I'm using ES 2.4.

Comment: Since you're creating the query yourself and thus are specifying `0.5h` as a static value, why not also replace `(?)` with 1800 seconds ? Note that the interval could also be as `1800s` instead of `0.5h`

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing the conversion on my own if its something ES could do for me. But there seems to be a more sinister issue here as I think about it some more; its not easy to convert something like "month" to seconds, because that conversion depends on which month it is. So I'm not sure how to proceed at all in that case.